# How can I create a temporary table using MySQL Connector/Python?

Tags: python, mysql, database-connection, temp-tables

I am using MySQL Connector/Python to run MySQL from my iPython notebook.

I am wondering, can I create a temporary table this way?

The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-ddl.html) says nothing about temporary tables, and makes it seem that you would have to define a table before using it.

I am trying something along these lines:

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='me',
                              password='something',
                              host='somewhere',
                              port='3306',
                              database='some_db')
 
query = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +\
"my_temp_table " +\
"AS " +\
"SELECT a_col" +\
"FROM 
  . . . 
;"
```

When I try this from iPython, it runs and gives no response, yet the temp table has not shown up in the database.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 3):

my englist is poor

i think ,the mysql TEMPORARY TABLE for current session .
when you close,the TEMPORARY TABLE  is over.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html
You can use the TEMPORARY keyword when creating a table. A TEMPORARY table is visible only to the current session, and is dropped automatically when the session is closed.